# Name for integrality relaxation in BQP problems

Tags: terminology, linear-programming, quadratic-programming, relaxations

Given a binary quadratic program, what is the name for the relaxation where the binary constraints are relaxed to $[0,1]$ box constraints?

For LPs this is normally called LP-Relaxation. However, since the problem is a BQP, is there an appropriate name for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called the *QP relaxation* or *quadratic relaxation*.  More generally, relaxing integrality yields the *continuous relaxation*.

Comment: Ok so the general term is  "continuous relaxation". Is "integrality relaxation" also accepted / common ?

Comment: Yes, but that phrase seems to be less common and instead often refers to the *process* of relaxing integrality rather than to the resulting *problem*.

Comment: Precise answer, very much appreciated ! Thanks.